# How to use STM32L0xx 's Comparator in Stop mode?

Tags: stm32, comparator

I want to use Comparator, for comparing external voltage with Vref in stop mode

so that if external voltage is more than Vref, wake up from stop mode and do something.

I read example code about Comparator, LPTIMER ... but they are not exact solution about my project

**so Can you give some idea or example about how to using Comparator in stop mode ?**

Comment: Are you sure the comparator keeps running in Stop mode and is a wakeup source ?

Comment: First you want to make sure the Vref is not disabled entering stop mode. Then you basically start the comperator and enter stop mode. It would be helpfull, if you post some of your code (configuration of pins, comperator, clocks).